# Flex - LDAP /Active Directory Login System - AMFPHP

Tags: apache-flex, active-directory, ldap, amfphp

I am hoping someone has seen some information on a way to authenticate to Windows Active Directory (LDAP?) from Flex -- or more specifically, I am using AMFPHP, so I believe I would need to authenticate from within AMFPHP / PHP.    ?      Or possibly there is a different direction I can head in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think can do this  directly from FLEX, but you can use server side technologies to that, it can be java/blazeDS or .net or PHP,

FLEX Should call Server side method and use its reponse for authentication, you can also do this using PHP [Lightweight Directory Access Protocol](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php)

Adobe is planning it with coldfusion [coldfusion.service.mxml Ldap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/coldfusion/service/mxml/Ldap.html)  
but its in beta thats why i dont recommend it

Hope that help

Comment: If you *really* wanted to, you could always implement your own LDAP library using the `Socket` class, but I would agree that using a middleware solution would probably fit your requirements better being it would be more manageable.